# ColorPicker in Flutter does not update when in Editing Mode

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the library **flutter_colorpicker** library. My Widget has a variable called **isEditing** to know that the screen is in editing mode. The editing mode fetches some data from a sqlite database, puts it on the screen and changes the logic of the **Save** button a bit.

The ColorPicker when isEditing is false, works fine. But it does not work on editing mode. When I click **Ready** on the color Picker, the Container does not changes the color and the color in the database remains the same.

Anyone knows what's happening?
Thank you.

```
class ManageCategory extends StatefulWidget {
  const ManageCategory({Key? key, required this.isEditing, this.category})
      : super(key: key);

  final bool isEditing;
  final Map<String, dynamic>? category; // <- Loaded trough sqflite in parent class.

  @override
  State<ManageCategory> createState() => _ManageCategoryState();
}

class _ManageCategoryState extends State<ManageCategory> {
  String title = '';
  final _nameController = TextEditingController();
  final _descController = TextEditingController();
  Color _color = Colors.blue;
  final _dbInstance = TimeManagerDB.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.isEditing) {
      title = 'Edit category';
      _nameController.text = widget.category!['name'];
      _descController.text = widget.category!['desc'];
      _color = Color(widget.category!['color']);
    } else {
      title = 'Create category';
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
        actions: widget.isEditing
            ? [
                IconButton(onPressed: onDelete, icon: const Icon(Icons.delete)),
              ]
            : null,
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        children: [
          Text(
            'Nome',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium,
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _nameController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
          Text(
            'Descrição',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium,
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _descController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
            maxLines: 4,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 60.0,
                width: 18.0,
                color: _color,
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 16.0),
              Text(
                'Cor',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium,
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          title: const Text('Choose a color!'),
                          content: SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: ColorPicker(
                              pickerColor: _color,
                              enableAlpha: false,
                              onColorChanged: (color) {
                                _color = color;
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          actions: <Widget>[
                            ElevatedButton(
                              child: const Text('Ready'),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      });
                },
                child: const Text("Choose"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 64.0),
          Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: onSave,
              child: const Text('Save'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**hey, should setState to rebuild the UI:**

```
onColorChanged: (color) {
  setState(() {
    _color = color;
  });
},
```

Comment: It does not work in editing mode, sadly. :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem moving the variables initializations to the initState().

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.isEditing) {
      title = 'Editar categoria';
      _nameController.text = widget.category!['name'];
      _descController.text = widget.category!['desc'];
      _color = Color(widget.category!['color']);
    } else {
      title = 'Criar categoria';
    }
```

}